# Confluent Kafka connect ElasticSearch ID document creation

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using the kafka connect elasticsearch connector to write data from a topic to an ElasticSearch index. Both the key and value of the topic messages are in json format. The connector is not able to start because of the following error:

```
    org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: MAP is not supported as the document id.
```

Following is the format of my messages (key  | value):

```
    {"key":"OKOK","start":1517241690000,"end":1517241695000}     |   {"measurement":"responses","count":9,"sum":1350.0,"max":150.0,"min":150.0,"avg":150.0}
```

And following is the body of the POST request I'm using to create the connector:

```
{
 "name": "elasticsearch-sink-connector",
 "config": {
 "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
 "tasks.max": "1",
 "topics": "output-topic-elastic",
 "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
 "type.name": "aggregator",
 "schemas.enable": "false",
 "topic.schema.ignore": "true",
 "topic.key.ignore": "false",
 "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
 "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false", 
 "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
 "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false", 
 "key.ignore":"false",
 "topic.index.map": "output-topic-elastic:aggregator",
 "name": "elasticsearch-sink",
 "transforms": "InsertKey",
"transforms.InsertKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
"transforms.InsertKey.fields":"key"
}}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I've found out a similar question on stackoverflow [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096936/confluent-kafka-connect-elasticsearch-document-id-creation) but I've got no luck with the answers.

[ES document ID creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096936/confluent-kafka-connect-elasticsearch-document-id-creation)

Answer (score 0):

You also need `ExtractField` in there

```
"transforms": "InsertKey,extractKey",
"transforms.InsertKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
"transforms.InsertKey.fields":"key",
"transforms.extractKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
"transforms.extractKey.field":"key"
```

Check out [this post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for replying Robin, I've also tried that but it didn't work either. I've finally modify the key to be a plain String and then the connector works fine but I'd really like to find out how to solve the initial issue.

Comment: It may be `ValueToKey` can't take fields from the existing _key_. Let me check.

Comment: Yes, I guess the ValueToKey only can take fields from the value of the message (but not from the key)

Comment: @ardlema how did you make it work with the key? i have the same issue i am trying to map the key of the topic to the document id of elasticsearch but it is not working... my key is a string still it doesnot work.

Comment: @user1945064 you're best off posting a new question so that people can help you with it there.